# how export glass color in blender 2.8

Tags: export, glass

I am trying to export a model with transparent material in fbx format I know that the format does not support different colors and need to after assemble the colors but with the transparent color I can not

shading glass

[image]

Settings I tried and failed

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the help